# TypeScript and Cypress can't return true/false in custom cypress command

Tags: typescript, cypress

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('checkIfTenantExist', (tenantName: string) => {
  let result: boolean = false;
  getTenant()
    .each(($tenant) => {
     if ($tenant.text() === tenantName){
       result = true;
     }
    })
    .then(() => {
      return result;
    });
});
```

I write tests using cypress and typescript. I would like to add custom cypress command which return bool. It always return false even if it was changed in if block. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, presuming `getTenant()` returns one or more elements (which it should considering you follow it with `.each()`).

But the way you use the custom command may be incorrect.

It should be used with a `.then()`

```js
cy.checkIfTenantExist('something').then(exists => {
  // further tests here
})
```

or with a `.should()`

```js
cy.checkIfTenantExist('something').should('eq', true)
```